# How to increase the size of /var for an Amazon aws ec2 centos 7.5 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to be able to increase the size of the /var filesystem of my EC2 instance "possibly" without having to detach the volume, and creating new volume and attach.

1. list block devices

> ```
> $lsblk
>      NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
>      xvda                  202:0    0  2.4T  0 disk
>      ├─xvda1               202:1    0  487M  0 part /boot
>      └─xvda2               202:2    0    2T  0 part
>        ├─ami-home          253:0    0   10G  0 lvm  /home
>        ├─ami-opt           253:1    0   20G  0 lvm  /opt
>        ├─ami-tmp           253:2    0   10G  0 lvm  /tmp
>        ├─ami-var           253:3    0   30G  0 lvm  /var
>        ├─ami-var_tmp       253:4    0   10G  0 lvm  /var/tmp
>        ├─ami-var_log       253:5    0   30G  0 lvm  /var/log
>        ├─ami-var_log_audit 253:6    0   20G  0 lvm  /var/log/audit
>        └─ami-root          253:7    0 19.5G  0 lvm  /
> ```

2. disk free ( as we can see, /var is 100% full )

$df -h

```
 Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
 /dev/mapper/ami-root            20G  1.8G   18G   9% / devtmpfs       
 7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev tmpfs  7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm tmpfs                          7.8G   17M  7.8G   1% /run tmpfs 7.8G     0  7.8G   0%
 /sys/fs/cgroup /dev/mapper/ami-var 30G   30G   53M 100% /var
 /dev/mapper/ami-opt       20G  330M   20G   2% /opt
 /dev/mapper/ami-home            10G   39M   10G   1% /home
 /dev/mapper/ami-var_log         30G   72M   30G   1% /var/log
 /dev/mapper/ami-tmp             10G   54M   10G   1% /tmp
 /dev/mapper/ami-var_log_audit   20G  488M   20G   3% /var/log/audit
 /dev/mapper/ami-var_tmp         10G   33M   10G   1% /var/tmp
 /dev/xvda1                     484M  162M  323M  34% /boot tmpfs      
 1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
```

3. get the existing size of the volume ( since I know the instance id )

> $aws ec2 describe-volumes --volume-ids vol-007310f0c754b2598
>
> ```
> >   {
> >       "Volumes": [
> >           {
> >               "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1c",
> >               "Attachments": [
> >                   {
> >                       "AttachTime": "2018-08-02T15:47:47.000Z",
> >                       "InstanceId": "i-047fa3b2aea60f7b3",
> >                       "VolumeId": "vol-007310f0c754b2598",
> >                       "State": "attached",
> >                       "DeleteOnTermination": true,
> >                       "Device": "/dev/xvda"
> >                   }
> >               ],
> >               "Encrypted": false,
> >               "VolumeType": "gp2",
> >               "VolumeId": "vol-007310f0c754b2598",
> >               "State": "in-use",
> >               "Iops": 720,
> >               "SnapshotId": "snap-00a77e9f750429974",
> >               "CreateTime": "2018-08-02T15:47:47.023Z",
> >               "Size": 240
> >           }
> >       ]   }
> ```

4. increase the size of the partition

   $aws ec2 modify-volume --region us-east-1 --volume-id vol-007310f0c754b2598 --size 2400 --volume-type gp2

result:

```
 {
     "VolumeModification": {
         "TargetSize": 2400,
         "TargetVolumeType": "gp2",
         "ModificationState": "modifying",
         "VolumeId": "vol-007310f0c754b2598",
         "TargetIops": 7200,
         "StartTime": "2018-08-06T06:57:21.000Z",
         "Progress": 0,
         "OriginalVolumeType": "gp2",
         "OriginalIops": 720,
         "OriginalSize": 240
     }
```

}

5. xfs_growfs -d /var does not modify the var

Error: data size unchanged, skipping

references:

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-initialize.html
3. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/cli-modify.html[enter link description here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/cli-modify.html)

So i tried:

```
$lvextend -l +200%FREE /dev/mapper/ami-var
  New size (7680 extents) matches existing size (7680 extents).
```

but:

```
> xfs_growfs -d /dev/mapper/ami-var meta-data=/dev/mapper/ami-var   
> isize=512    agcount=4, agsize=1966080 blks
>          =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
>          =                       crc=1        finobt=0 spinodes=0 data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=7864320, imaxpct=25
>          =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=1 log      =internal               bsize=4096   blocks=3840, version=2
>          =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1 realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0,
> rtextents=0 data size unchanged, skipping
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after the above steps: do

1. pvresize /dev/xvda2
2. lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ami-var
3. xfs_growfs -d /dev/mapper/ami-var
   Done! /var is extended